# Google Cloud Function returns vague 'Connection error' when trying to connect to Google CloudSQL (mysql) instance

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, database-connection, google-cloud-sql

I was trying out this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-picadaily-lab1/index.html?index=..%2F..cloud#9) code snippet by Google. I wanted to alter it in a way so that the Vision API metadata would be stored in a relational MySQL using the CloudSQL service - following [their examples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/cloud-sql/mysql/mysql/server.js) on how to connect Cloud Functions with CloudSQL.

The code I ended up deploys but upon triggering the function (by uploading a new image) I get a vague 'connection error' in the logs with no more information. This is my code at this moment:

```
const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
 
const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();

const winston = require('winston');
const {LoggingWinston} = require('@google-cloud/logging-winston');
const loggingWinston = new LoggingWinston();
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  transports: [new winston.transports.Console(), loggingWinston],
});

const createUnixSocketPool = async (config) => {
  const dbSocketPath = "/cloudsql"
  return await mysql.createPool({
    user: 'root',
    password: 'mypassword',
    database: 'mydatabase',
    socketPath: `${dbSocketPath}/cs-03-282615:europe-west1:mydatabase`,
    ...config
  });
}
 
const createPool = async () => {
  const config = {

    connectionLimit: 5,
    connectTimeout: 10000,
    acquireTimeout: 10000,
    waitForConnections: true,
    queueLimit: 0,
  }
    return await createUnixSocketPool(config); 
};

let pool;
const poolPromise = createPool()
  .then(async (pool) => {
    return pool;
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    logger.error(err);
    process.exit(1)
  });
 
exports.vision_analysis = async (event, context, pool) => {
    console.log(`Event: ${JSON.stringify(event)}`);
 
    const filename = event.name;
    const filebucket = event.bucket;
 
    console.log(`New picture uploaded ${filename} in ${filebucket}`);
 
    const request = {
        image: { source: { imageUri: `gs://${filebucket}/${filename}` } },
        features: [
            { type: 'LABEL_DETECTION' },
            { type: 'IMAGE_PROPERTIES' },
            { type: 'SAFE_SEARCH_DETECTION' }
        ]
    };
 
    // invoking the Vision API
    const [response] = await client.annotateImage(request);
    console.log(`Raw vision output for: ${filename}: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
 
    if (response.error === null) {
        // listing the labels found in the picture
        const labels = response.labelAnnotations
            .sort((ann1, ann2) => ann2.score - ann1.score)
            .map(ann => ann.description)
        console.log(`Labels: ${labels.join(', ')}`);
 
        // retrieving the dominant color of the picture
        const color = response.imagePropertiesAnnotation.dominantColors.colors
            .sort((c1, c2) => c2.score - c1.score)[0].color;
        const colorHex = decColorToHex(color.red, color.green, color.blue);
        console.log(`Colors: ${colorHex}`);
 
        // determining if the picture is safe to show
        const safeSearch = response.safeSearchAnnotation;
        const isSafe = ["adult", "spoof", "medical", "violence", "racy"].every(k =>
            !['LIKELY', 'VERY_LIKELY'].includes(safeSearch[k]));
        console.log(`Safe? ${isSafe}`);
 
        if (isSafe) {

            const pool = await poolPromise();
           
            

            const stmt = 'INSERT INTO sc_03_metadata_schema (labels, color, created) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
            await pool.query(stmt, [labels, colorHex, NOW()]);
            
            console.log("Stored metadata in CloudSQL");
        }
    } else {
        throw new Error(`Vision API error: code ${response.error.code}, message: "${response.error.message}"`);
    }
};
 
 
function decColorToHex(r, g, b) {
    return '#' + Number(r).toString(16).padStart(2, '0') +
                 Number(g).toString(16).padStart(2, '0') +
                 Number(b).toString(16).padStart(2, '0');
}
```

The full error is as such:
[Error Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnuVZ.png)

Comment: Could you please include the full error text please ?

Comment: I have updated original post with the error. Thank you!

Comment: Lovely Thanks George. It's best not to use images to represent text for Accessibility reasons and nobody could take any pertinent information from the log and paste elsewhere (though in this case as you state in the title the error is very vague). Not my area but hopefully a SO user will help you soon on your first question ..

Answer (score 0):

I understand you wish to connect to your Cloud SQL MySQL instance via a Cloud Function. From referencing the public documentation [Connecting from Cloud Functions to Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions#connecting_to) it seems that “process.env.DB_SOCKET_PATH || “ was not included when instantiating your dbSocketPath.

In regards to the vague error message, this is a known issue, one of which is currently being investigated by the Cloud Functions specialists. I would suggest that you take a look at the [Public Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/155215191) and click the star icon to subscribe to the issue for further updates and click the bell icon to be notified of updates via email. We do not have an ETA on the resolution of this issue at this time.